# jquery - getting perfect .height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please look at this code

http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/VG47Z/3/

There is nothing wrong there. So now check this one

http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/4GrsD/6/

You can find that the `$(document).height()` value is differing in the second jsfiddle and the red box is placing down beyond the area. Why is it so?

I want to place the red box at the bottom most inside the document area and I don't want to use this

```
bottom: 0px;
```

Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: I appears to have been placed properly for me.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use `bottom: 0`?  That is a much more elegant way of handling it.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Because I want to know why that is not working

Comment: @JonathanSampson Is it? could you tell me why I'm not getting here?

Comment: @rnk Can you tell us what browser, and version, you're testing in?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Chrome very latest version

Comment: also not working in firefox seems it is same for every browser:(

Comment: +1 for using Chrome! I can't develop websites without it!

Answer (score 1):

at a q glance, it looks  like the problem is because you are mixing

```
    .css("height");
```

with 'computed height

```
   .height();
```

use .css("height") to get the doc height as well as setting the final position.

**update as comment:** apologies ( less haste )

```
  $("body").css("height");
```

returns the height value only **if** one is set in css or a recent programs set it.

**try**

```
   $("body").height()
```

instead of $(document).height();

document is larger than body

Comment: How can I use .css("height") for getting doc height?

Answer (score 0):

Your question : How can I use .css("height") for getting doc height?

```
$(document).height();
```

if you got an object with margins you can use

```
$(object).outerHeight();
```

It will take all his height

Comment: with width() it's the same thing